# how to use Postmedia digital cordova plugin (DFP)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

I would like to use DFP (double click for Plublisher) for my android app, I already have the generated scripts and markup as below:

```
       <script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
var src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
'//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="' + src + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
})();
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.defineSlot('/*****/****_APP_1024x66', [1024, 66], 'div-gpt-ad-    ********-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.pubads().enableSyncRendering();
googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
googletag.enableServices();
</script>



DOCUMENT BODY

<div id='div-gpt-ad-**********' style='width:1024px; height:66px;'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-*********');
</script>
</div>)
```

But, it does not display on Mobile (android project). That's why I would like to use the DFP plugin (PostMedia), but I do not know how to use that?  as the plugin itself would not be good enough. 
for instance, I have already had the code(above) to put in my app, but I wanna know how can i integrate that plugin with my code. 
Note: In the plugin we have:
       createBannerAd: function (options, successCallback, failureCallback) {
     var defaults = {
      'adUnitId': 1404187116182-0,
      'adSize': (250, 150),
      'tags': undefined,
      'networkId': 4271715,
      'backgroundColor': "#fff"
        };
what if we want to have bunch of ads and of course we have bunch of codes generated by Google and FDP? we need to create a service ? or what? 
I really appreciate any response  a head, 
I am using Cordova 2.8.1 / AngularJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how we use it

```
  var successCreateBannerView = function() {
      //console.log("addBanner Success");
      DFPPlugin.requestAd({
          'isTesting': false
      }, success, error);
  };

  var success = function() {
      //console.log("requestAd Success");
  };
  var error = function(message) {
      //console.log("requestAd Failed " + message);
  };


  var options = {
      'adUnitId': '/xxx/xxxx', // Replace the /xxx/xxxx with your adslot
      'adSize': 'BANNER',
      'tags': {},
      'backgroundColor': '#FFFFFF'
  };

  DFPPlugin.createBannerAd(options, successCreateBannerView, error);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I used a different plugin though since there was no answer for this then.

Comment: @user3610928 what plugin did you use? looking for the same

Comment: Well, I don't remember what I used then, but if you planing to have it in mobile, what I did at last was I ran the script I got from my dfp account in my local web and that scripts ran/handled differently and displays another script in the inspect. And if you use that script in mobile it will work. got me? or not?